# Get last row on page

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I've got an excel form I'm filling with data. The form is laid out to fit within the width of a page. I need to print the signature line on the last row on the last page but it cannot be printed on any other page. The data may be any number of rows. Some data may enlarge the row height so we also don't know the number of rows per page.

Is there a way to find the last row on the last page or do you have any suggestions of how to insert the signature line on the last page? I'm ok if it's in the footer but I don't know how to create a different footer on the last page

Comment: Don't you have a variable that increments with each row you write?

Comment: `Excel.Range last = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);` … to get the last “non-empty” row… then… `int FirstEmptyExcelRowBelowData = last.Row + 1;` I am guessing this may be what you are looking for.